# How to use HTTP PUT in java to send payload with custom header?

Tags: java, json, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x, put

I wrote the following code to send HTTP PUT request  with payload which contains JSON object .
I used Apache HttpClient but can't figure out the error, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong ? 
It gives this compilation error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.(AbstractHttpClient.java:5)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.(DefaultHttpClient.java:7)
>     at Test.main(Test.java:26)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONObject keyArg = new JSONObject();
            keyArg.put("name", "XYZ");
            keyArg.put("email", "XYZ");

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI url = new URI("www.XYZ-SERVER.com");

            HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(url);
            putRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            putRequest.addHeader("Content-Length", "LENGTH");
            putRequest.addHeader("Key", "ad412f36a2eecbcd5c0e323e");
            putRequest.setEntity((HttpEntity) keyArg);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(putRequest);

        }
```

Comment: depends on the client version you have. check the samples http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/examples.html for one that sets headers with an interceptor.